# Congrats sfdcfox on reaching 300k rep

Tags: discussion

100k, 200k and now 300k. Such an amazing feat. Heartily congrats [Brian](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) and thanks for your amazing help in making SFSE a great success. I can't count how many times you have helped me in reaching a solution or understanding a difficult concept. You rock. :)

[image: sfdcfox 300k]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Welcome to 2020!

It's been an incredible journey so far. 300k is indeed impressive, even more so when you look at how small our network is, relatively speaking (compared to Stack Overflow, for example). I've personally answered about 8 of 100 questions we have on the network, and I've probably read close to 80% of the questions that have been posted since I've joined.

I've learned so much, and I've had so much support. I cannot possibly thank everyone enough for their continued support. My personal life has been rocky since joining, and I've kept most of it from everyone but my closest friends.

I feel like it's not appropriate to share my personal problems, but even if you didn't know my struggles, everyone's positive support, comments, answers, edits, votes, etc have all been an inspiration and kept me afloat in the darkest of times.

I look forward to contributing even more in the future, continuing my personal growth, and helping those that need it. I'm so glad that I found salesforce.com, and the community that they foster. Everyone has been amazing. I simply can't stress that enough.

So, here's to the next 100k!

Comment: Great going Brian. You are an example for all of us to share more knowledge and learn collectively with the community.

Answer (score 16):

Another truly astounding stat: ~7.8 *million* people reached by sfdcfox's contributions through the years.

We can't show enough gratitude for everything that you do for this community!

Answer (score 13):

To achieve 300k is a fantastic accomplishment - well done Brian!

Thank you for being so generous with your time so that we can all benefit from your knowledge and experience!

Comment: I second @Robs on this.  I only started getting into SF dev a little over a year ago and when I start digging for info on a problem I'm trying to work through, in almost all cases Brian has posted an insightful comment or solution.  Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 13):

I remember when you got 100K and everyone ooh'ed and aw'ed. Now, it seems as though 1 million is readily achievable. A truly remarkable achievement and one wonders how you do any other work at all.

I and the community are extraordinarily grateful for you contributions

Answer (score 7):

What an achievement! Salesforce and programing as a second career for me after 20 years in the Army. I would not be where I am now without people like sfdxfox.

Answer (score 7):

Many Congratulations!!. I think synonym for **Salesforce StackExchange** is **sfdcfox**. I remember when I joined this community, you were somewhere around 90k reputation and after 2 years its more than 300k.

It does takes effort and time to reach this milestone. Thank you for being kind and helping the community with the vast amount of knowledge that you have.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 6):

Congrats on Reaching 300K. It's really a great achievement. Well Done @sfdcfox

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to people like Brian, the lives of others become easier and more interesting. Personally, I was often helped by the answers of Brian. It is almost impossible to overestimate the contribution he has made to our community.

Keep up the good work and thank you @sfdcfox

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, truly an amazing feat, and I rarely go through a day without coming across a sfdcfox influenced SFSE post, no joke!

Thank you for enriching the Salesforce community and also a personal thanks - I get warm fuzzy feelings anytime I see your comment/answer on my posts!

Answer (score 5):

This is inspiring!!!

Congratulations, you are the rockstar of the SFSE community. We are grateful to have you here. Thanks for your contribution to the community.

Answer (score 3):

You are an amazing and generous man. I know I have asked many questions and you have always answered. I remember telling my wife about your tenacity with the SFSE community years ago. Thank you for all you do and hoping things get smoother personally for you.

Answer (score 2):

I remember when I introduced a colleague to this stack exchange.

I told them;

> You can just ask any Salesforce question and sfdcfox will usually answer you pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations @sfdcfox. You are amazing, you are generous, you are helpful. But most importantly you are humble and kind. When my questions get a response from you, i know i will learn something that will stay in my mind. Just as you strengthen up our knowledge each day, I pray that you get the strength and wisdom to smoothly surmount all the challenges life bring you.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! I've only ever posted one question (today in fact, lol) but I've been lurking for a few years and it seems that every question I've looked up has had a great answer from you, or at least a comment with additional useful insight. Definitely the most consistently helpful poster on the site from what I've seen.